# Hacknet problem

Tags: hacknet

When I got hacked by Naix, I did everything right; I downloaded his x-server.sys, then I rebooted my computer, and it worked fine. Now I don't know what to do, and I accidentally deleted all my .sys files.

Then I realised it was my computer

I go to his proxy thing, and download all his .sys files, but when I reboot, bootcfg.dll and netcfgx.dll had an error. The other two are fine.

What do I do? Should I restart from the beginning?

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking you have to restart the game at that point. You're only supposed to pick up x-server.sys from Naix. I wouldn't be surprised if the game didn't handle you deleting your own files that weren't part of the scenario well.

After the Naix hack + recovery, you're supposed to either respond to the quest you currently have in your mailbox to progress in the main story *or* hack him back for a series of side quests. (Scan the computer you got x-server.sys from and go from there... more detail here would be a spoiler. :))

Answer (score 1):

The game only knows that it's supposed to put .sys system files inside the /sys folder. Since netcfgx.dll and bootcfg.dll are .dll application extensions, they would be put in the /home folder. Only the game's command line is required for this. Run these commands:

1. cd home
2. mv netcfgx.dll ../sys/netcfgx.dll
3. mv bootcfg.dll ../sys/bootcfg.dll
4. reboot -i

What you're doing will first change directory to the /home folder, then move the two files to /sys, the reboot -i will instantly reboot the in-game computer.